# Ajax success not executing after POST action is called ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have this form:

```
@{ using (Html.BeginForm(@*"MakeOffer", "Product", FormMethod.Post, *@new { id = "offerForm", productId = Model.ProductId, sellerId = Model.SellerId }))
{
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Price, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
@Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => modelItem.Price, "{0:#.#}", new { placeholder = "Input your price", id = "offerText", name="offerPrice" })
@Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => modelItem.ProductId)
@Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => modelItem.OffererId)
@Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => modelItem.SellerId)
<input id="offersubmit" type="submit" class="btn" value="Submit" />
}
```

This is my Ajax function:

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#offersubmit").click(function (e) {
            if ($(this).valid()true) {
            var valdata = $("#offerForm").serialize();
            alert(valdata);
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Product/MakeOffer",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
                data: valdata,
                success: $(document).ready(function () {
                    $('#offerText').val('');
                })
            })
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Now the form is getting passed to the `MakeOffer` action, but I'm getting a 500 error and the success function isn't getting called.
These are my script tags at the end:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
```

Comment: you need to remove the `$(document).ready(..)` portion, it should be `success: function(data) { .. }`

Comment: @hijinxbassist ah thanks that fixed it. Now when the text box is cleared, I get a validation message that the field is required, because now it is empty. Any idea how to make it not appear after it gets cleared?

Comment: Does that field need validation?  If not, remove the validation from the html/js.  I think you'll have better luck with a new question that outlines the issue with relevant markup/code added.

Comment: @hijinxbassist yeah it does need a `[Required]` validation. Anyway fixed it by using `.val(null)` instead of `.val('')`.

Comment: You either need to leave the value there, or remove the validate attribute from the input.  There are hacky solutions, but they are hacky and should be avoided.  eg. hide the original textbox and replace it with an empty textbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the `$(document).ready(..)` portion of the success callback.

It should be

```
success: function(data)
{
    $('#offerText').val('');
}
```